# Force new line to horizontally align with css

Tags: html, css

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/SfTuD/1/

HTML:

```
<label class="longLabel">Create Document</label>

<input class="radioButton" checked="checked" value="true" id="Yes" type="radio"></input>

Allowed    

<input class="radioButton" value="false" id="No" type="radio"></input>

Not Allowed

<span class="description">A user with this permission will be allowed to create new Documents, Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</span>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    min-width:165px;
}
label.longLabel {
    width:165px;
}
input.radioButton {
    margin-right:5px;
}
.description {
    font-style: italic;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

I would like the description span to stay to the right of the radio buttons. That is, the new line of the description should be aligned with "A user..."

I have tried display: inline-block, but that forces the whole span to a new line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a suggestion: wrap the inputs with the labels in `li` elements, the `float` or `inline-block` the `li`s.

Comment: There's no such thing as `</input>` in (X)HTML

Comment: Looks fine in FF 24. What browser are you seeing the issue in?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your css:

```
 display: inline-block;
```